# Error in beta release on play console

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

Hi I want to release a new beta version of my App. But I am getting error 
Errors
Resolve these errors before starting the rollout of this release.

Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

But I am not using READ_PHONE_STATE in my app.
My permissions in android manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

and in gradle dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
```

I don't know what is the issue please help

Comment: no problem, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

This was an bug in the version `12.0.0` which was later fixed in the latest version, as explained here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android